# The "/" character being dropped in a simple JavaScript scrape

Tags: javascript, xml

In my script I have:

```
     xmlFile = "C:\Timelines\Data\AKM.XML" 
     alert(xmlFile)
```

The alert displays as :

```
     C:TimelinesDataAKM.XML
```

The line defining xmlFile is written into the script by an external program. But I have tried deleting it, and rekeying with NotePad, with same result.

TIA

Andrew

Comment: The backslash is an escape character. This is basic, basic language features. Use the Internet and read about JavaScript strings. (And a backslash is different from the forward slash in your title.)

Comment: What is a "JavaScript scrap"?

Comment: FYI it's "scrape"

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes are used to escape special characters. As in this case none of them are followed by [known escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript), they are ignored.

To escape the backslash itself to show an actual backslash, repeat it:

```
 xmlFile = "C:\\Timelines\\Data\\AKM.XML"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`xmlFile = "C:\\Timelines\\Data\\AKM.XML"`

Because `\` will be take it as escape character